# Alternatives for "demand"

Tags: vocabulary, formality, paraphrasing

> "The job Y demands familiarity with Z."

How do you say the above sentence, when the familiarity with the product Z is not necessary, but helpful as a part of job Y?

Just to give a little context, the previous sentence is:

> "I have worked as X and Y. The job Y demands familiarity with Z."

For clarification, let's say X and Y are professional positions and Z is a product. And the purpose of the writer is to say that the job led to learning Z.

Comment: I think "requires" would have the same meaning as "demands", right? As I said one can do Y without being familiar with Z. The writer chose to learn Z for the job.

Comment: What's wrong with using "the job Y led to learning Z", as you final sentence suggests?

Comment: A/Some knowledge of Z is helpful for job Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've veered a bit toward the end of your question from what you'd initially set out to ask, which is:

> How do you write the above sentence, when  familiarity with Z is not necessary, but helpful as part of Y?

In which case I suggest rephrasing the sentence thus:

> Familiarity with Z **facilitates** Y.

Or perhaps,

> Familiarity with Z nicely **complements** Y.

I hope you realize this is different from *Y* leading to learning (about) Z.

The cause-effect relationship is inverted in the latter.

Answer (score 1):

“I have worked as X and Y. The job Y benefited from familiarity with Z."

> Benefit = to be helped by something or to help someone
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/benefit)